# How does hourly job, works in germany

Tags: germany

I have a question guys, you know in germany they work with hours, and when you are working in a company as a tools producer, you know they work with time on the register paper you stap into computer before and after finishing the work. My question is, if it’s 8hours someone work a day and when the stap-papers says that this job have to be completed by 20hours but the worker finish that same job for 8hour, what will be the worker  payment? Is it 8hours payment, which is the 8 hours of working per day or 20hours payment that is written on the job the worker just finished?

Comment: What does "stap-papers" mean?

Answer (score 1):

If you work in a company and you have a contract for X hours you get paid for X hours.
Using some form of time registration is just for checking that your actually work your X hours. Or companies may have a more detailed system where your say *I worked A hours on project P, and B hours on project Q* - then it is for internally tracking how much time was spent on the different projects.

Whether you work hard/good enough is something completely different - your superiors (or colleagues) will let you know. Your boss may say *You have to finish this in Y days*, but you still get paid according to your contract.